# Hash field before indexing

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database table where I have a field named `source`. I want an index on the `source` field, so it's faster to search.

However, I have heard sometime that if `source` will contain a lot of similar values it's smarter to make a new field, i.e. `sourceHash` and make the index on that field instead because hashes of similar values doesn't look similar at all.

My question is if this is true and a valid approach in 2018? Usually I would believe that the DBS vendor would have solved something like this?

Comment: What kind of data containing in the `source` field?

Comment: Read this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41405/varchar-index-will-hashing-value-make-it-faster

Comment: You are referring to something known as _cardinality_.  If `source` has very few unique records, then it has _low_ cardinality.  However, if it has many records which are _similar_, but not the same, then it can still have high cardinality, and would probably benefit from an index.

Comment: Second comment: So I don't see the point of hashing, because the value determines the result coming from the hashing function.  If there are many duplicates, the hashed values will also be duplicate, and vice-versa.

Comment: Well I think what I heard back then (but may not be true) is that if I hash the values, then the resulting index will be 'better' / more balanced than an index of the original `source` field because the values in that field are very similar.